# How to generate this code dynamically in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a large list of data and another list of patterns. I'm trying to filter data using the patterns. Here's my code using some sample data:

```
dataList = [ '4334 marked val 5656 bin', 
    '76-67-34 done this 99', 
    'bin ket AZZ3R434 pid' 
]

for data in dataList:
    regexList = [ re.search(r'val ([\d]+) bin', data),
            re.search(r'bin ket ([A-Z\d-]+)\b', data)
        ]

    for reg in regexList:
        if reg:                   #If there's a match
            #...do something...
            break
```

In the above code in *regexlist* the 're.search()' part is getting repeated again and again. I want to keep only a list of patterns, something like below:

```
regexList = [ 'val ([\d]+) bin',
        'bin ket ([A-Z\d-]+)\b'
    ]
```

And use these patterns one by one with re.search() later. I tried using eval() and exec() both, but just kept getting errors.

I would also like to know whether 'regexList' is getting created again and again under for loop?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you would need to do this with eval/exec. Just pass the pattern to re.search inside the loop:

```
regexList = [
    r'val ([\d]+) bin',
    r'bin ket ([A-Z\d-]+)\b'
]
for pattern in regexList:
    if re.search(pattern, data):
        ...
```

Comment: Yeah it can be done this way. Cool. But was wondering how to do it with exec/eval.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataList = [ '4334 marked val 5656 bin', 
    '76-67-34 done this 99', 
    'bin ket AZZ3R434 pid' 
]

regexList = [
         r'val ([\d]+) bin',
         r'bin ket ([A-Z\d-]+'
]
for data in dataList:
    for reg in regexList:
        if  re.search(reg,data):                   #If there's a match
            #...do something...
            break
```